# Save my document files with the firebase current uid instead of a random one

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So look when my user registers himself his ID in the firebase database is randomly generated and I want to have the UID of the newly registered user as the document´s id in firebase how can I change that ? I haven´t found any function to make the document save as a String or something like that..

Here is my register code:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText UserName, FullName, eMail1, eMail2, Password, Day, Month, Year;
    private Button registerButton;
    private CheckBox male, female, other;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
    public String currentUserId, username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
        UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_username);
        FullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_name);
        eMail1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_email);
        eMail2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_email_2);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password);
        Day = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_birthday_day);
        Month = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_birthday_month);
        Year = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_birthday_year);
        registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
        male = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.register_male);
        other = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.register_other);
        female = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.register_female);
        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CreateNewAccount();
            }
        });
    }

    private void CreateNewAccount() {
        username = UserName.getText().toString();
        String fullname = FullName.getText().toString();
        String email1 = eMail1.getText().toString();
        String email2 = eMail2.getText().toString();
        String password = Password.getText().toString();
        String day = Day.getText().toString();
        String month = Month.getText().toString();
        String year = Year.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please type in your username...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(fullname)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please type in your full name...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email1)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please type in your eMail...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email2)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please retype your eMail again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(!email1.equals(email2)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"You entered two different emails...? Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please type in your password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(day)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter your birthday day...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(month)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter your birthday month...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(year)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter your birthday year...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(!male.isChecked() && !female.isChecked() && !other.isChecked()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Chose your gender...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(male.isChecked() && female.isChecked()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please choose only one gender...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(male.isChecked() && other.isChecked()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please choose only one gender...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(female.isChecked() && other.isChecked()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please choose only one gender...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            loadingBar.setTitle("Creating New Account");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are creating your new Account...");
            loadingBar.show();
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email1, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        SaveAccountInformation();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Your account was created please check your email for an activation mail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                        SendUserToMainActivity();
                    }
                    else{
                        String message= task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error Occured: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void SaveAccountInformation() {
        currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        String gender;
        username = UserName.getText().toString();
        String fullname = FullName.getText().toString();
        String day = Day.getText().toString();
        String month = Month.getText().toString();
        String year = Year.getText().toString();

        if(male.isChecked()) {
            gender = "male";
        } else if(female.isChecked()){
            gender = "female";
        } else {
            gender = "other";
        }

        HashMap userMap = new HashMap();
        userMap.put("username", username);
        userMap.put("gender", gender);
        userMap.put("fullname", fullname);
        userMap.put("birthday", day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
        userMap.put("uid", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        userMap.put("verified", "false");
        db.collection("users")
                .add(userMap)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });
    }

    private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `add()`.

`add()` will just add new document in the collection with random id.

But when you provide documentid and set method. It creates document with current user uid and set the data to that specific id.

Use `set()` and provide the document id to firestore

```
db.collection("users").document(currentUserId)
    .set(userMap)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            //Do what you want
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
```